# No Scala mutable list 

Tags: scala, immutability, mutable

Scala has both a mutable and an immutable Map ,
but it has only an immutable List. 
If you want a mutable List you need a ListBuffer.

I don't understand why this is so.
Any one knows?.

Comment: Is not there a [MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.html)?

Comment: `List` has a very specific meaning in computer science and Scala followed that (instead of continuing Java's abuse of this term :-D).

Comment: This is a duplicate, but, sadly, I can't find the older one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can choose between these:

- [**`scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList`**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList)
- [**`scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList`**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList)
- [**`scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer)
- [**`scala.collection.mutable.MutableList`**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MutableList)

So, yes, Scala has mutable lists :-)

Comment: For more on which one to use see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049213/which-scala-mutable-list-to-use

Answer (score 6):

I hope that this article may be of some use to you. The diagram at the bottom of the page is particularly useful in providing the mutable and immutable classes.

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html

Comment: The accepted answer by Jean-Philippe Pellet is more direct, and gives you some classes that you can throw into your code just to get past your problem.  However, Graham actually *answered* your question as to "why this is so?".  I hope you'll read the link that he provided, as it will help you better understand the idea behind mutable and immutable collections in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mutable `List`, but it is called [`Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Buffer). The article linked by Graham goes into more depth, but I thought there should be a specific answer to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is a `trait` -- like Java's `interface` --, while `List` is a `class`, a concrete implementation of a `Seq`. There are mutable and immutable `Seq`, just like for `Map`.

This may be confusing to Java programmers because, in Java, `List` is an `interface`, whose (main) implementations are `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. Alas, Java naming is atrocious. First, `ArrayList` is not a `List` by any stretch of imagination. Also, the interface has methods that are not really related to any traditional list.

So, if you want mutable/immutable equivalence, look to concrete subclass implementations of `Seq`.