# LinkedList vs MutableList in scala

Tags: scala, pointers, data-structures, scala-collections

Below, both descriptions of these data structures: (from *Programming in scala* book)

> **Linked lists**
>
> Linked lists are mutable sequences that consist of nodes
> that are linked with next pointers. In most languages null would be
> picked as the empty linked list. That does not work for Scala
> collections, because even empty sequences must support all sequence
> methods. LinkedList.empty.isEmpty, in par- ticular, should return true
> and not throw a NullPointerException. Empty linked lists are encoded
> instead in a special way: Their next field points back to the node
> itself. Like their immutable cousins, linked lists are best operated
> on sequen- tially. In addition, linked lists make it easy to insert an
> element or linked list into another linked list.
>
> **Mutable lists**
>
> A MutableList consists of **a single linked list** together with a pointer
> that refers to the terminal empty node of that list. This makes list
> append a con- stant time operation because it avoids having to
> traverse the list in search for its terminal node. MutableList is
> currently the standard implementation of mutable.LinearSeq in Scala.

Main difference is the addition of the last element's pointer in `MutableList` type.

Question is: What might be the usage preferring `LinkedList` rather than `MutableList`? Isn't `MutableList` strictly (despite the new pointer) equivalent and even more practical with a tiny addition of used memory (the last element's pointer)?

Comment: You have a nice comparision of mutable lists here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049213/which-scala-mutable-list-to-use

Comment: I will not fill okay by returning a mutable list from a function, or by receiving a mutable list in a function - that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `MutableList` wraps a `LinkedList`, most operations involve an extra indirection step. Note that wrapping means, it contains an internal variable to a `LinkedList` ([indeed two, because of the efficient last element lookup](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/MutableList.scala#L42)). So the linked list is a required building block to realise the mutable list.

If you do not need prepend or look up of the last element, you could thus just go for the `LinkedList`. Scala offers you a large choice of data structures, so the best is first to make a checklist of all the operations that you require (and their preferred efficiency), then choose the best fit.

Generally, I recommend you to use [immutable structures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html), they are often as efficient as the mutable ones and don't produce problems with concurrency.

Comment: Thanks, I would add that `LinkedList` is quite similar to `Node` element presents in `java.util.LinkedList` type (in Java). `MutableList` wrapping `LinkedList`(in order to be able to locate last element), is thus similar to `java.util.LinkedList`. Therefore, both code designs (building mutable linked lists) are a matter of taste.