# How can I add a member to list(immutable) in scala?

Tags: scala

I'd like to add a member to list but the list is immutable. I was told that Scala prefers immutable list in many perspective. Thanks in advance.

```
 class Family[T]{
    val list: List[T] = List();
    def add(member: T): Unit = { member :: this.list }
    def getFamilyNames(f: T => String){
        println(list.size)
        list.foreach {
            println
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on which part you want to be immutable. If you want an immutable list, you can keep it inside a mutable variable, i.e. `var list = List.empty[T]`, and then *update the reference* to that list.

Answer (score 0):

you can mutable List called `ListBuffer[T]` or `ArrayBuffer[T]`

```
class Family[T]{

  val list = ListBuffer[T]()

  def add(member: T): Unit = { this.list+=member }

  def getFamilyNames(f: T => String){

    println(list.size)
    list.foreach {
      println
    }
  }

}

class SomeSpecs extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("adds value to family") {

    val fam  = new Family[String]
    fam.add(new String("some value"))
    fam.add(new String("some other value"))

    fam.list shouldBe ListBuffer("some value", "some other value")
  }
}
```

Please read [Which scala mutable list to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11049213/432903) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` method doesn't do what you're expecting.
`member :: this.list` does return a new list with the extra member added to it. However, you're explicitly discarding it's return value which is of type List[T]. That is, prepending an element in a list doesn't modify the list in place: it just returns a new immutable List.
What you likely want to have is something along the lines of:

```
var list: List[T] = List() // this must be a var to reassign to it
...
def add(member: T): Unit = { list = member :: this.list }
```

Usually, though, you want to avoid *side effects*, if you want to stick to a functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have everything immutable than you should create new instance of Family because in other cases the instance of Family is mutable

```
class Family[T](list: List[T] = List()){
  def add(member: T): Unit = new Family(member :: this.list)
}
```

If Family is a Bulder of something than better to use a mutable collection. If it is not a builder, please review usage of it, may be you don't need the method 'add' at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It help me a lot